# How to find last digit IF next column has a condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-2019

In Tab 1 I have 2 columns, B with the material numbers of 11 digit, and C with the commentary.
In Tab 2 I have one column (E) with the 10 material number digits.
In column F I have to find the last number (the 11th from the column B in Tab 1), that can wither be 1 or 2. If the commentary in column C is equal to "Incorrect Variant" I need to put 2, if the last digit in column B is a 1, I need to put a 1, and if the last digit is 2, I need to put two.

I'm having troubles finding a working formula, because the order of the material number is scattered.
What formula should I attach to the =E2& in order to find either 1 or 2 from the other data in column B?

Comment: Something along the lines of `if(index(match())="Incorrect Variant",2,index(match())). You'll have to modify with `mod` and/or `text` depending if the numbers are all digits or alphanumeric. Also, this will only work if the 10 and 11 digit number sequence are unique.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share either Workbook or sample data as screen shot, since the info you are trying to pass is insufficient to realize the core issue !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND(F4,$A$4:$A$7),$B$4:$B$7)="Incorrect Variant",2,RIGHT(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND(F4,$A$4:$A$7),$A$4:$A$7),1))
```

[image]